# Icon color changed when move tabs - vuej.s

Tags: vue.js, tabs

I have a group of `v-chip` in a `v-tab`, on the `v-chip` I have an icon - the icon color is changed when clicking on him.

my problem: if I click on one icon, the color is changed but when I move to the other tab, the icon color returns back to the base color.

any idea how can I save the icon color when moving tabs?

Attached here my code:

```js
SetContinueInError(myChip, e) {
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  myChip.continueInError = myChip.continueInError == true ? false : true;
  target.style.color = myChip.continueInError == true ? "yellow" : "gray"
},

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<v-tab v-for="item in items" :key="item.index" @click="latest = false">
  <span style="
                      font-size: 16px;
                      font-weight: bold;
                      font-family: 'Segoe UI Emoji';
                      text-transform: capitalize;
                      float: left;
                    ">{{ item.tab }}</span
                  >
                </v-tab>
              </v-tabs>

              <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
                <v-tab-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.index">
                  <v-row>
                    <v-col cols="3" sm="4" v-if="tab!=5&&tab!=6&&tab!=7">
                      <v-autocomplete
                        style="margin-left: 15px"
                        v-model="categories[tab]"
                        :items="FiltersLists[tab]"
                        :label="tab != 0 ? 'Name' : 'Filter By'"
                        item-text="category"
                        solo
                      ></v-autocomplete>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="3" sm="4" v-if="tab == 0">
                      <v-autocomplete
                        style="margin-left: 5px"
                        v-model="values[tab]"
                        :items="ValuesLists"
                        label="Options"
                        solo
                      ></v-autocomplete>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="3"
                      :sm="tab == 5 ? 8 : 4"
                      v-if="tab != 0 && tab != 2 && tab != 4"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        :style="tab==5||tab==6 || tab==7 ? 'margin-left:15px' : ''"
                        :disabled="latest"
                        v-model="values[tab]"
                        :label="tab==5 ? 'Type your Command here':tab==6?'Type kit version':tab==7?'Enter kit path...':'Your version...'"
                        solo
                      ></v-text-field>                     
                      
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="3" sm="4" v-if="tab!=0&&tab!=2&&tab!=4&&tab!=5&&tab!=6&&tab!=7">
                      <v-switch
                        style="margin-top: 4px !important"
                        v-model="latest"
                        @change="
                          latest ? (values[tab] = 'Latest') : (values[tab] = '')
                        "
                        label="Latest"
                      ></v-switch>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="3" sm="4" v-if="tab == 5|| tab==6">

                      <v-radio-group                    
                        v-model="categories[tab]"
                        column
                        style="margin-top: 2px !important"
                      >
                        <v-radio
                          style="font-family: 'Segoe UI Emoji'; color: black"
                          :label="tab==5?'Controller':'Corporate'"
                          :value="tab==5 ? 'RunCmd - CNT':'ME driver - Corporate'"
                        ></v-radio>
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <v-radio
                          style="
                            color: black !important;
                            font-family: 'Segoe UI Emoji';
                          "
                          :label="tab==5?'DUT':'Consumer'"
                          :value="tab==5?'RunCmd - DUT':'ME driver - Consumer'"
                        ></v-radio>
                           <v-radio
                           v-if="tab==6"
                          style="
                            color: black !important;
                            font-family: 'Segoe UI Emoji';
                          "
                          label="Slim"
                          value="ME driver - Slim"
                        ></v-radio>
                      </v-radio-group>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="3" sm="4" style="margin-left: 18px !important">
                      <v-tooltip top>
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                          <v-chip
                            v-on="on"
                            class="ma-2"
                            style="font-size: 20px"
                            height="20px"
                            pill
                            clickable
                            :color="
                              categories[tab] == '' || categories[tab] == null
                                ? ''
                                : 'orange'
                            "
                            @click="AddRequirement()"
                            outlined
                            label
                          >
                            <md-icon
                              :class="
                                categories[tab] == '' || categories[tab] == null
                                  ? ''
                                  : 'blinking'
                              "
                              >add</md-icon
                            >
                          </v-chip>
                        </template>
                        Add requirement
                      </v-tooltip>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                  <span v-if="chips.length>0" style="margin-left: 15px; font-size: 16px">Your Actions:</span>
  <v-card class="scroll" height="230px" width="700px" style="margin-left: 15px">
    <v-icon @click="chips=[]" style="float: right;">close</v-icon> <br>
    <span v-if="chips.length==0" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-down:10px !important; font-size: 16px">Your Actions:</span><br v-if="chips.length==0"><br v-if="chips.length==0">
    <div>
      <draggable :list="chips">
        <v-flex v-for="chip in chips" :key="chip.category">
          <v-chip style="margin-left:10px;" v-model="chip.name" color label close @click:close="RemoveRequirement(chip)" outlined class="mb-2">

            <span>{{ chip.category }}</span
                              >&nbsp;
                              <v-divider
                                class="mx-4"
                                color="black"
                                inset
                                vertical
                                v-show="chip.value.toString() != ''"
                              ></v-divider>
                              <span>{{ chip.value.toString() }}</span>
            <v-tooltip bottom><template v-slot:activator="{on}"><i v-on="on" class="material-icons" style="color:gray !important; margin-left:7px" @click="SetContinueInError(chip,$event)" :v-model="chip.name">error_outline</i></template>Click to continue on error</v-tooltip>
          </v-chip>
        </v-flex>
      </draggable>
    </div>

  </v-card>
  <v-card-actions>
    <div style="padding-right: 30px !important; padding-left: 30px !important;">
      <v-checkbox v-model="getHealthCheckBox" label="Run only if DUT is connected"></v-checkbox>
    </div>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-chip color="#0D47A1" label class="ma-2 white--text float-right" @click="$emit('hidedialog')">Close</v-chip>
    <v-chip color="#0D47A1" label class="ma-2 white--text float-right" :disabled="chips.length <= 0" @click="
                          StartRun(false);
                          waitingForWorkspaces = true;">Execute</v-chip>
  </v-card-actions>
  </v-tab-item>
  </v-tabs-items>
```

Comment: It's best to show the code along with your description

Comment: Add the code above.

Comment: Where is the tab you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks, added now...